# How to break an integral including absolute value?

Tags: integration

I want to know what is the main way to break an integral including absolute value? Is it important that where does the absolute value appear? In the exponential or in the error function or elsewhere for example? Suppose I have a simple integral as follows$\DeclareMathOperator{\erf}{erf}$
$$
f(r_e)=A\int_{0}^{\infty} g(r_e,r_p) \;\erf(B \lvert r_e-r_p \rvert) \; \exp(C\lvert r_e-r_p\rvert)\;dr_p \tag{1}
$$
I thought that I can break (1) as follows
\begin{align}
f(r_e)=A\Biggl(&\int_{0}^{r_e} g(r_e,r_p) \;\erf(B ( r_e-r_p )) \; \exp(C( r_e-r_p))\;dr_p \\+&\int_{r_e}^{\infty} g(r_e,r_p) \;\erf(B ( r_p-r_e )) \; \exp(C( r_p-r_e))\;dr_p\Biggl) \tag{2}
\end{align}
where $A$, $B$ and $C$ are some complicated constants and $g(r_e,r_p)$ is a complicated function of $r_e$ and $r_p$ but doesn't has absolute value terms.
However when I check the result of (2) with (1) they aren't the same (just (1) gives the correct answer). In fact I evaluate (1) numerically and (2) analytically by Mathematica. In this vein I asked [a relevant question in Mathematica SE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/244966/why-are-the-numerical-and-analytical-evaluation-of-this-integral-not-the-same) by details yesterday, but unfortunately no one gave answer, so I thought maybe my mathematical procedure is wrong and ask it here. Any help would be much appreciated to find the fault.

Comment: I see nothing invalid in your conversion of equation (1) to equation (2) in your question.  Is it possible that you made a mistake in evaluating equation (2)?  Also, I noticed that in both (1) and (2), you left the expression $C|r_e - r_p|$ unchanged.  I wonder if this might have led to a computational error.  I see no reason that $C|r_e - r_p|$ can not (also) be changed to $C(r_e - r_p)$ or $C(r_p - r_e)$ depending on which integral you are currently working with.

Comment: @user2661923 Thanks and sorry I just forgot to change it during writing the question. I edited it, however I have used the correct form in my calculation. You can see my code in Mathematica SE for more details.